Enforce two functions have the same signature (only by using types)
I want to enforce copy function to extends original function. but the trick is - the order of parameters of fnGenerator is opposite.
Can it be done?
function fnGenerator<Original extends Copy, Copy extends Function>(copy:Copy,original:Original){}

function original(props:{a?:number,z:number}):number { return 2}
function copy(props:{a:number}):number { return 1}

// right now `original` has compilationerror instead of `copy`
fnGenerator(copy,original)


Real usecase:
function fallback<OriginalFn extends Function>(props: {fallback:OriginalFn}) {
  return function (target: any,
   propertyKey: string, 
   descriptor: Omit<PropertyDescriptor,'value'> & { value?: OriginalFn}
) {
    return descriptor
  };
}

class MyClass1 {
  // I expect a compilation error but it works 
  @fallback({fallback: (props: {x:number,z:number})=>{ return 0} })
  static method1(pros:{x:number, z?: number}):number {
    return 1
  }
}


Is this a duplicate of the question you deleted? I’m trying to understand your use case.

@jcalz it's not a duplicate. it's the next step. my goal is to create a fallback method decorator that accepts different function pointer as a parameter and activate it when the original method fails. I want to make sure both methods has "same" signature. the above question shows my problem as the fallback is the first param while the original method is the second. I edited my question with the fallback example.

I truly don't understand, sorry. Your use case is a curried function but your example is a single function. The curried function has target: any instead of the equivalent to your example, which looks like this if I understand correctly. Now both have compilation errors... why do you care which argument the error is reported on for the first example? How does the decorator fit into this (and keep in mind that your decorator is using old-style TS experimental decorators, you might want to note that). Could you please [edit] to clarify?

Both examples have the same problem. It seems the real use case is more confusing (my fault I guess). can you tell me at least if the question has possible answer?

I don’t understand the use case or why you’re trying to fight against the type system so I don’t know what to say here. If someone asked you how to put their shoes on before their socks wouldn’t you want to understand why so that you can guide them toward something more reasonable?

Okay I got you. Sory for the long explanation: I didn't implement the decorator just for simplicity. If we look at Class1: the specified fallback should extend method1. not the opposite because the decorator will call the fallback with the same params of method1. the problem: I want compilation error because here fallback dont extend method1. Did you understand my problem?

And did you look at the playground link I posted in my second comment? That's what I thought you wanted. If you didn't look and it is what you wanted, I could write up the answer, but I still have no idea why you care about which of the two arguments to fnGenerator gets the error, as long as there's an error somewhere. If you did look and it isn't what you wanted, could you please [edit] the question to explain as clearly as possible what you're looking for?

thank you, I tried to make the same signature in mthod and I expect no error but I get an error ( I added ? to z so they will look similar).

I'm afraid I have no idea what you're talking about. I'm not sure if it's a language barrier or some other communication problem but unless you can [edit] the question to make what you're trying to do much clearer, I don't think I can do anything to help, and I'll just disengage. Sorry, and good luck.

@jcalz look at the solution. Thank you for your great help man!

Well, that was hard one. Full discussion.
My first solution. But it didn't work (see the playground in the link)
I thought there was a typescript bug.
Then it's just method parameter bivariance.
Solution; Kind of a workaround to parameter bivariance:
function fallback2<MethodArgs extends unknown[],MethodReturn,FallbackFn extends (...args: MethodArgs) => MethodReturn>(props: { fallbackFn: FallbackFn }) {
  return function(target: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: MethodArgs) => MethodReturn>
  ) {
    // implement fallback logic...
    return descriptor
  };
}

class MyClass1 {
  // I expect a compilation error because FallbackFn does not extend Method1Fn
  @fallback2({ fallbackFn: (props: { x: number,y:number }):number => { return 0 } }) // works! why??
  static method1Class1(pros: {x: number }): number {
    return 1
  }

  @fallback2({ fallbackFn: ():number => { return 0 } }) // works! why??
  static method1Class2(x:number): number {
    return 1
  }

      // I expect a compilation error because FallbackFn does not extend Method1Fn
  @fallback2({ fallbackFn: (y:number,z:number):number => { return 0 } }) // works! why??
  static method1Class3(x:number): number {
    return 1
  }

  @fallback2({ fallbackFn: (y:number,z?:number):number => { return 0 } }) // works! why??
  static method1Class4(x:number): number {
    return 1
  }
}

